# Enterprise architect shows weird symbol. What does it mean?

Tags: modeling, enterprise-architect

sometimes a red triangle appears over some (not all!) of my requirement artifacts that I have constructed before starting more detailed UML work and development.

I have no idea what causes it or what it is meant to express.
What's more, I cannot get rid of it. ;)

[image: What does this triangle tell me?]

As far as I know this has nothing to do with the UML or SysML specification - or does it?

Can anyone explain?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has nothing to do with UML or SySML. What is says is that someone bookmarked the element. You may have done so by accident by pressing shift-spacebar.

If you search the help file for "Manage Bookmarks" you will get the full explanation.

Comment: Thanks. I guess that's exactly what has happened. ;)