# What does this little red triangle indicate on an Enterprise Architect UML diagram?

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

Using Sparx Enterprise Architect 12.1, I've done something to a UML element which has resulted in the element being decorated with a little red arrow, in all the diagrams in which the UML element appears. For the life of me, I can't figure out what the arrow means, or which setting or property it corresponds to, and I can't figure out how to get rid of it. Can anybody help?

[image: Sparx Enterprise Architect UML element with small red arrow]

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142386/enterprise-architect-shows-weird-symbol-what-does-it-mean

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a bookmark. Select it and hit `Shift`+`Space` and it will toggle. There is also a predefined search which allows to find bookmarked elements.

[image]

N.B. This once was a recurrent question on Sparx' forum with top ranking ;-)

Comment: Well, I did Google it, but didn't get a hit on the Sparx forums. Thanks!

Comment: The keyboard shortcut appears to be Shift+Space rather than Ctrl+Space (at least in EA 12.1 default settings)

Comment: Oh. I wrote this right from memory. Not using it often in practice. Will correct it. Thanks! Btw: enter triangle in EA's help. It should how give a hint.